# Using Cross Apply on Greenplum

Tags: sql, greenplum, lateral-join

I would like to know if there's a way to use cross apply the way I'm using it on MSSQL.

```
Select
    pt.PersonName,
    psc.Charges,
    psc.Taxes
from tbl.PersonTable pt
cross apply(
        Select
        PersonName,
        sum(Charges) Charges,
        sum(Taxes) Taxes
        From tbl.PersonSumCharges psc
        Where psc.PersonID = pt.PersonID
        Group by PersonName
    )psc
```

I'm quite new to Greenplum so I apologize for this noobish question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `join` and `group by`:

```
Select PersonName, sum(Charges) as Charges, sum(Taxes) as Taxes
From tbl.PersonTable pt left join
     tbl.PersonSumCharges psc
     on psc.PersonID = pt.PersonID
Group by pt.PersonName;
```

I don't think that Greenplum supports lateral joins.